# IIS 7.0 with pipeline mode = Integrated doesn´t load any image/css in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a full system working in IIS 5.1 ...
I migrated to IIS 7.0 with pipeline mode classic all works fine, but with pipeline Integrated my images/css are not loaded...

I´m using ASP.NET 3.5 with a Web Application...

Any help?

Comment: Can you clarify "not loaded"? Is it 404, a 500, a permissions error, etc?

Comment: No error at all... Simply the images dont appear...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In IIS 7 when you install the ASP.NET modules, static content is not installed by default. You will need to go into programs and features, then "Turn windows features on or off".

Under IIS section, drill down into WWW services, Common Http features, and check "Static Content".

Without that css, images, html, and other non-dynamic content will not show up.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, my static content was not installed.  To change the setting under server 2008, get to Server Manager, open Roles and click Web Server (IIS).  Once it populates find the Role Services section then Add Role Services to install the Static Content.

Comment: Thank you! This one had me puzzled for a while. The Server 2008 setting was hard to find (thanks, Microsoft).  Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

You can use some HTTP sniffing tool (Firebug or Fiddler) and check for failing requests. If you find such requests you can inspect the error message returned by the server.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this to be a side effect of having a corrupted default document inheritance. We typically add "login.aspx" to the top of a the default documents list in the parent (Default Web Site) configuration. When this somehow became corrupted displaying this same symptom.
The fix was to remove the inherited value and re-add it. I could then see static content again using a .NET 4.0 integrated app pool.