# ASP.NET (3.5, Webforms) doesn't properly load CSS when user is not (yet) authorized

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

I have a really funky issue here... I've inherited a fairly large ASP.NET 3.5 Webforms project, and one issue is that when starting up the app, the login page is shown - but without any styling whatsoever....

This is the `Login.aspx` markup (simplified):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="MyWeb.Web.Login" MasterPageFile="~/MyWebPublic.Master" 
         UICulture="Auto" Culture="Auto" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   ... some div's, textboxes etc.
</asp:Content>
```

This page is based on a "public" master page - something like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyWebPublic.Master.cs" Inherits="MyWeb.MyWebPublic" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/layout.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

So you can see - I do have links to two CSS stylesheets in my master page, which are in fact present.

I my `web.config`, I specifically allow everyone (even non-authorized users) access to my login page:

```
<!-- Allow access to login page for everyone -->
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

And yet - when I run the project, I get an ugly looking page without **any** CSS applied. In the Firefox error console, I discover:

> The stylesheet `http://localhost:50855/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fstyles%2flayout.css` was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". Login.aspx
>   The stylesheet `http://localhost:50855/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fstyles%2fstyle.css` was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

So it almost seems as if ASP.NET is trying to load the CSS, determines this is an unauthorized user, and redirects to the login page - even when attempting to load the CSS!

Once I've logged in - everything's fine, my CSS is applied as expected...

What on earth is happening here?? I've never seen this behavior EVER before - in all other cases, even the first page you get to (login or otherwise) gets its proper styling by applying the referenced CSS .......

Any thoughts, ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are authorizing any users to access to the login page but not to content in the styles directory. As the css is being served through ASP.NET it is not allowing access until the user is authenticated. Add the following to your web.config under the existing location element.

```
<location path="styles">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Also check this link for a potential solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/804061/1444207